# How is the PLINQ AsParallel function passing data to a function when called within the same scope

Tags: .net, ironpython, plinq

Using IronPython, I am calling some function in parallel that is within the same function the parallelized data is in to keep it in the same scope.

In multiprocessing of CPython it is pretty clear the data must be explicitly passed to a subprocess, how many subprocesses are open, etc.  This makes it easy to understand the overheads.

In the case of PLINQ, how is code run in parallel?  I.E.:

Is there another instance of ironpython that is run and everything is imported again? For example `import myHugeLibrary` would be run each time a new python instance is created of the file.

`CalcParallel()` takes in some arrays of data and a dictionary.  Within this scope is a function `computation()` that should be run in parallel, and it calls another function `checkVals()` in the main script. Since `computation()` is in the same scope that `AsParallel()` is called, I don't need to explicitly pass it the data to be used. However does this mean the data is copied to each process/thread, or is kept as a reference and is fine when it is only being read (not write)?  If it is copied, is it copied each time an item is calculated, meaning if there are 100 items in the list and 10 threads, will it copy the data 10 times as it puts 100 items in 10 chunks, or does it copy 100 times?

Likewise, the example C_dict data is modified after some amount of data is calculated, and before the next round of data is run (based on results, it adds more things todo). Is this modified data then copied again when the parallel process runs?

Below is some example structure of code that I am wondering about.  Its not really about the code itself but I wrote this to just illustrate the question, even if its not the proper way.

```
# get LINQ dependencies
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Core")
import System
clr.ImportExtensions(System.Linq)
from System.Threading.Tasks import *

#import some huge library that takes time
import myHugeLibrary

max_val = 4 #some global value used within the thread

def checkVals(itemToCheck,A_vals,B_vals):
    #check against some global value
    if itemToCheck < max_val:
        return 0
    #do something else with A_vals

def CalcParallel(todo_list,A_vals,B_vals,C_dict): 
    """
    take in some data that is used in the functions that will
    run in parallel.
    """

    total_list = []

    #make a function that will be run in parallel
    def computation(itemToCheck):
        checkedItems = checkVals(itemToCheck,A_vals,B_vals)
        results = []
        for item in checkedItems: 
                results.append(item)
        return results

    #in a loop keep sending something out for calculation in parallel until
    # all the combinations are done
    while len(todo_list) != 0:
            #use AsParallel on a list of items
            results = todo_list.AsParallel().SelectMany(
                            lambda itemToCheck: 
                                computation(itemToCheck) ).ToList()

            todo_list = []
            for item in results:
                if item not in total_list: 
                    total_list.append(item)

                    #do some modification to the dictionary that was passed in
                    C_dict[item] = None

    return total_list


def main():
    todo_list = [3,3,2,4,5,4,1,3,4,5,1]
    A_vals = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
    B_vals = [-1,-3,-5,-7,-9]
    C_dict = {0:-3,4:-7}

    newVals = CalcParallel(todo_list,A_vals,B_vals,C_dict)

    print(newVals)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

PLINQ acts somewhat similar to the TPL. The work is partitioned/scheduled/dispatched using relatively lightweight constructs. There are no additional ironpython processes and the work is most likely scheduled on a pool of worker threads (via tasks) meaning that the overhead should be quite small.

Everything you are using is captured by scope/reference and you should avoid conflicting write operations by either using thread-safe shared collections or, better yet, by modelling your data flow in a way that results can just be merged at the end (like you are doing with SelectMany). This should not cause copies of your data.

In order to ensure efficient execution the blocks of work need to be of reasonable size to avoid unexpected overheads.

Comment: hi again, thanks for the info!  If nothing is copied because it is in scope, the .tolist() function is just aggregating the results into a list right?  What is involved in the overhead then, is it only the startup of the thread or is there some other aspect as well?